# JSONP ajax won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

My previous version of this ajax code worked perfectly during testing with `google-chrome  --disable-web-security` filling a select element with options however now that I rewrote the code a bit to work with jsonp it won't work and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: xmlrpcproxy + '?callback=jsonpcallbackfunc', // <--- returns valid json if accessed in the browser
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "jsonp", // Pay attention to the dataType/contentType
    dataType: 'jsonp', // Pay attention to the dataType/contentType
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpcallbackfunc',
    });

function jsonpcallbackfunc (data) {
    var firstoption = '<option value="select" selected>Please Select</option>';
    jQuery("select#ItemIDSelect").html(firstoption);
    var i;
    var erplist = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(data);
    for (i = 0; i < erplist.length; ++i) {
                jQuery("select#ItemIDSelect").append('<option value="' + erplist[i] + '">' + erplist[i] + '</option>');
    }
    }
```

The called server page returns

```
jsonpcallbackfunc(["admin2", "Administrator", "Afdeling XCV", "Agrolait", "Angel Cook", "Arthur Gomez", "ASUSTeK", "Axelor", "Axelor", "Ayaan Agarwal", "Bank Wealthy and sons", "Benjamin Flores", "Best Designers", "Brian Williams", "Camptocamp", "Chamber Works", "Chao Wang", "Charlie Bernard", "China Export", "Clement Marsot", "Coin gourmand", "Daniel Jackson", "David Simpson", "Delisle Albert", "Delta PC", "Demo User", "Donald Thompson", "Edward Foster", "Elec Import", "Epic Technologies", "Fabian Semal", "George Wilson", "Global Solutions", "Jacob Taylor", "Jacque Marseille", "James Miller", "Jan Bart", "Jessica Dupont", "John M. Brown", "Joseph Walters", "Julia Rivero", "Kevin Clarke", "Laith Jubair", "Laura Castro", "Lucas Jones", "Luc Maurer", "Luminous Technologies", "Mark Davis", "Marketing Business", "Mediapole", "Michel Fletcher", "Millennium Industries", "Morgan Rose", "Natuurpunt vzw", "Nebula Business", "Nhomar Hernandez", "Paul Williams", "Peter Mitchell", "Phillipp Miller", "Pizza Inn", "Richard Ellis", "Robert Anderson", "Robin Smith", "Roger Scott", "Seagate", "Sergio P\u00e9rez", "Spark Systems", "Steven Hamilton", "Tang Tsui", "Template User", "The Jackson Group", "The Poste", "Think Big Systems", "Thomas Passot", "Tom Pintens", "Vauxoo", "Vicking Direct", "William Thomas", "Your Company", "Your Company, Birmingham shop", "Your Company, Chicago shop", "Zhi Ch'ang"])
```

**UPDATE: the function fires now and adds the static option to the select element. However`var erplist = JSON.parse(data);` gets unexpected token a (from admin2) what do I need to change for JSON.parse(data) to not fail, do I change data somehow?**

Thank you for reading!

Comment: The alert(data) never shows and the console displays the following log `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://0.0.0.0:1885/?callback=jsonpcallbackfunc&callback=jsonpcallbackfunc&_=1378719349147"` the _func&_=1378719349147_ bothers me I must say, how do I get rid of it? Same for the double _callback=jsonpcallbackfunc_, I'm just afraid to change too much on my own as not to deviate wrongly from a jsonp example I build this from.

Comment: What do you mean "My previous version of this ajax" .. Have you upgraded your jquery plugin??

Comment: Why are you specifying `jsonpCallback` anyway? Why not let jQuery generate the function and choose a (random) name? FYI, `contentType` specify the format of the data you are *sending* to the server. (a) you usually don't send JSONP (b) you are not sending any data anyway.

Comment: @Ganesh I meant the previous version of this code, I used json succesfully before this, i.e. without a function wrapped around the data

Comment: @FelixKling because the documentation example for web.py that I use serverwise failed to read the value of _ in the url, so I manually make a response without looking at the url like so: `b = json.dumps(a)
 return 'jsonpcallbackfunc(' + b + ')'` As I don't need a different function name everytime anyway

Comment: Ah. If you are not reading the `callback` parameter on the server anyway then you  don't need to include it in the URL. The `_` has nothing to do with JSONP, it's how jQuery prevents the browser from caching the request/response.

Comment: Is `jsonpcallbackfunc` defined in global scope? If not, it cannot be called.

Comment: @FelixKling If you could tell me how to clean up my url to just `http://0.0.0.0:1885` that'd be quite neat. I really hope you can help me with my main problem though. Which is the second function not firing or crashing before it even can execute the first line =/

Comment: it's defined within several functions including a ready document function, might be a scope problem yeah

Comment: @FelixKling good the function is firing now! the "Please Select" is added as an option to the select element! Weird enough the items from the list aren't added to the select though. `var erplist = JSON.parse(data);` gets unexpected token a as error, it worked fine before jsonp

Comment: JSONP is nothing else than JavaScript. The value of `data` is already an object, not a string containing JSON. You cannot parse it. Just use `data` directly or `var erplist = data;`.

Comment: @Yes! That's it! You may make an answer out of it Felix, everything is working now.

Comment: @FelixKling please make an answer out of your comments so I can  accept and upvote it :)